# c++ multiple template template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm reading some references online and I'm confused about template template argument. In particular I do not understand how the inner template parameter are passed according to their position. Perhaps an example will help to understand what is my confusion

What I was trying to do is the following. I have

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename DepA, typename DepB>
class aClass {
   ...
};
```

What I exect is that `DepA` must have `A` as template argument and `DepB`, `B`. In this way I would like to recast

```
aClass<int, double, std::vector<int>, std::deque<double>>
```

simply to

```
aClass<int, double, std::vector, std::deque>
```

What should I write in my template definition?

Comment: `aClass<int, double, std::vector, std::deque>` - this will not compile.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way to use template template parameter to achieve something like this?

Comment: What I mean is the fact that the above will not compile. You wish to make something that is impossible.

Comment: The second example in an answer does compile through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename DepA, typename DepB>
class aClass;


template <class A, class...As, class B, class...Bs, template<class...>class DA, template<class...>class DB>
class aClass<A, B, DA<A, As...>, DB<B, Bs...>> {
  // ...
};
```

is one approach; this enforces that the DepA/DepB take A/B as the first argument.  It does not get the syntax you want:

```
aClass<int, double, std::vector<int>, std::deque<double>>
```

but rather enforces that `int` and `double` be passed to 3rd and 4th arguments as the first argument.

But you want the template to inject it for you.  To do that:

```
template<class A, class B, template<class...>class DA, template<class...>class DB>
class aClass {
  using DepA = DA<A>;
  using DepB = DB<B>;
  // ...
};
```

now

```
aClass<int, double, std::vector, std::deque>
```

works; note that

```
aClass<int, double, std::array, std::deque>
```

does not work, as `array` takes a non-type template parameter.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_size {
  template<class T>
  using array = std::array<T,N>;
};

aClass<int, double, fixed_size<3>::template array, std::deque>
```

this does.

Comment: Your first approach does not compile: `type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list`

Comment: @user14063792468 Clarified, I assume you where doing something different than I did with the first approach.

Comment: "It does not get the syntax you want" - end qoute. The other code works, and it surprises me, how far did C++ go.